# Installing Git via Homebrew doesn't switch default to the Homebrew one

Tags: git, failed-installation

I have OS X Lion, and it comes with Git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26).

I then used Homebrew to install Git 1.7.10.1, and everything went fine.

But then when I did `git --version`, it still showed Git version 1.7.7.5.

Does anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your path order on your `.bashrc` and put `/usr/local/bin` (which Brew uses) before `/usr/bin` (which has the default git). It should do the trick.